# What does pending mean as far as WorkManager states?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to use `ExistingWorkPolicy` to make some code run that needs to be unique and run to completion only one time.

The [documentation of ExistingWorkPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy) of `REPLACE` and `KEEP` talking about `pending (uncompleted) work`. But the [documentation of Work States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation) only talks about `Enqueued`, `Running`, `Cancelled`, `Failed`, and `Succeeded`.

I want to know what exactly does `pending` or `uncompleted` means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pending (uncompleted) work` means everything that is not in the `completed` state. `Cancelled`, `Failed`, and `Succeeded` are `completed` states.

**Edit**

If another WorkRequest will be enqueued with REPLACE policy `WorkManager` guide [states](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#unique-work) that currently running worker will be stopped and the new one will replace it.

The actual killing of the worker will be dependant on its implementation.

Any `ListenableWorker` descendant will receive `ListenableWorker.onStopped()` to clean up after itself

Comment: So if I use `REPLACE` and something is `Running`, what happens? does it stop it and start it over?

Comment: I will add a little adit to address this question